# Swagger Error, Could not resolve reference: #/components/schemas/User in express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I want to use Swagger in express. but I can't setting schemas

Error line is

> Resolver error at
> paths.user/{email}.get.response.200.content.application/json.schema.$ref
> Could not resolve reference: #/components/schemas/User

in Swagger docs

here is my File Structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4ouq.png

and this is my code

main.js

```
// test-main rest api 
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const UserRoute = require("./routes/user_routes.js");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
var swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const swaggerOption = require("./swagger/swagger.js")

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.use("/api/user", UserRoute);

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
      success: true,
    });
  });

const specs = swaggerJsdoc(swaggerOption);
app.use("/api-docs",
    swaggerUi.serve,
    swaggerUi.setup(specs, {explorer: true})
);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server start"));
```

swagger.js

```
const options = {
    definition: {
        openapi: "3.0.0",
        info: {
            title: "Project-A Express API with Swagger",
            version: "0.1.0",
            description: "Project-A api",
            license: {
                name: "MIT",
                url: "https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html",
            },
            contact: {
                name: "LogRocket",
                url: "https://logrocket.com",
                email: "info@email.com",
            },
        },
        servers: [
            {
                url: "http://localhost:3000/api",
            },
        ],
    },
    apis: ["./routes/*.js", "./swagger/*.js"],
};

module.exports = options;
```

user_model.js

```
const mysql = require("../database/connect.js");
const table = "USER";
const uuid = require("uuid");
// uid varchar(50) not null unique,
// nickname varchar(12) not null unique,
// email varchar(20) not null unique,
// password varchar(20) not null,
// phone varchar(11) not null unique,
// authtype int not null,
// usertype ENUM("ADMIN", "SELLER", "BUYER") not null DEFAULT "BUYER",

/**
 * @swagger
 *  components:
 *   schema:
 *     User: 
 *      type: object
 *      required:
 *        - uid
 *        - nickname
 *        - email
 *        - password
 *        - phone
 *        - authtype
 *        - usertype
 *      properties:
 *        uid: 
 *          type: string
 *        nickname: 
 *          type: string
 *        email:
 *          type: string
 *          format: email
 *          description: Email for the user,
 *        password:
 *          type: string
 *          format: password
 *          description: password,
 *        authtype:
 *          type: int
 *          description: authtype,
 *        userType:
 *          type: string
 *          description: usertype,
 *        example: 
 *          uid: 123123jlkjlkdajfldaj
 *          nickname: dongwon
 *          email: dongwonkim@naver.com
 *          password: 1231231
 *          authtype: 1
 *          usertype: "ADMIN"
 */

const User = function(user){
    this.uid = user.uid;
    this.nickname = user.nickname;
    this.email = user.email;
    this.password = user.password;
    this.phone = user.phone;
    this.authtype = user.authtype;
    this.usertype = user.usertype;
}

User.findAll = function(result){
    mysql.query(`select * from ${table}`, (err, res)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            result(null, res);
        }
    });
}

User.findByEmail = function (email, result) {
    mysql.query(`Select * from ${table} where email = ?`, email, (err, res) =>{
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            result(null, res);
        }
    });
};

User.create = function(nickname, email, password, phone, authtype, usertype, result){
    const uid = uuid.v1();
    mysql.query(`insert into ${table} values (${uid},${nickname}, ${email}, ${password}, ${phone}, ${authtype}, ${usertype})`, (err, res)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log(`Create New User: ${uid}`)
        }
    });

}

module.exports = User;
```

user_routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var userController = require("../controller/user_controller.js");

/**
 * @swagger
 * tags:
 *  name: User
 *  description: 유저 관리
 */
/**
 * @swagger
 * paths:
 *  user/get-all:
 *   get:
 *      tags: [User]
 *      summary: 유저 정보 모두 가져오기
 *      description: 모든 유저 정보 가져오기
 *      response: 
 *          "200":
 *            description: 모든 유저 정보 가져오기 성공
 *            content: 
 *              application/json:
 *                  schema: 
 *                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
 */
router.get("/get-all", userController.findAll);

/**
 * @swagger
 * paths:
 *  user/{email}:
 *   get:
 *      tags: [User]
 *      summary: 특정 이메일을 가진 유저 가져오기
 *      response: 
 *          "200":
 *            description: 일부 유저 정보 가져오기 성공
 *            content: 
 *              application/json:
 *                  schema: 
 *                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
 */
router.get("/:email", userController.findByEmail);
router.post("/sign-up", userController.userSignUp);

module.exports = router;
```